# How to ignore CDATA tags?

Tags: php, cdata, libxml2

I'm trying to make an html parser, but when I load the html I get warnings like this

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Invalid char in CDATA 0x1C in Entity, line: 1302

Here is the code I use

```
class Parser
{
public $url=null;
public $html=null;
public $tidy=null;
public $head=null;
public $head_xpath=null;


function __construct($url){
    $this->url=$url;
    $this->html=file_get_contents($this->url);
    $this->tidy=tidy_parse_string($this->html);
    $this->head=new DOMDocument();
    $this->head->loadHTML($this->tidy->head());
    $this->head_xpath= new DOMXPath($this->head);

}
}

$x=new Parser("http://www.guardian.co.uk/politics/2012/mar/24/vince-cable-coalition-banking-row");
```

I searched around and found the LIBXML_NOCDATA constant, but I don't know how to set it.
So how could i completely ignore CDATA?

Comment: And I guess replacing blindly it in contents is not an option, because it might be in some article?

Comment: What are you trying to parse out of this HTML page?

Comment: @Artjom Kurapov I tried replacing the cdata tags with str_replace, but it still gives warnings and I cant allways be sure I removed them because some people write them like // (with lots of spaces here)      <![cdata[ .

Comment: I put this page because it has cdata in it. I'm looking for meta tags in general

Comment: Can you post the offending line from the xml? If it's well-formed cdata it shouldn't be throwing that error. Looks like you may have a character encoding issue.

Comment: I will use this to parse user submited pages, so there is no point in trying to find the issue with the cdata. What I need is a way to just get rid of it, so i dont get the warnings. Suppressing the warnings does not help either.

Comment: Are you in control of the user submitted data? Can't you enforce utf-8 character encoding? I suspect a user may be submitting an invalid character encoding which is why you can't parse the xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->html = preg_replace('~//\s*?<!\[CDATA\[\s*|\s*//\]\]>~', '', $this->html);
```

should work but haven't really tested it.